# Refactoring Code to assert at compile time instead of throwing an exception at runtime

Tags: c++, c++17, assert, throw, static-assert

Consider the following code example, a simple template class wrapper with basic overloaded arithmetic operators. In this class's `operator/` I'm using the ternary operator to throw an exception if division by 0 is detected otherwise, I'm returning the calcuation.

*some.h*

```
#pragma once

#include <cassert>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T>
struct Var {
    T var;
   
    // ... other operators
 
    const auto operator/(const Var& rhs) {        
        return ((rhs.var == 0) ? throw std::exception("Division by 0") : (var / rhs.var));
    }
};
```

Here's the driver program:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "some.h"

int main() {
    try {
        Var<int> t1{ 4 };
        Var<int> t2{ 0 };
        auto t3 = t1 / t2;
        std::cout << t3 << '\n';
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Unknown Exception\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And this will compile and build and when we run it (I'm using Visual Studio), it will throw an exception giving this message to the console

```
Division by 0

C:\Users\...\source\repos\Data Structure Samples\x64\Debug\Data Structure Samples.exe (process 8756) exited with cod
e 1.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the conso
le when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

Okay, this is simple enough and it works.

---

Let's say that I want to refactor this code with two primary objectives:

- First, Abstract the Operators away from the class
- Don't want to throw an exception, but would rather assert at compile time.

The class would transform into this:

*some.h*

```
#pragma once

#include <cassert>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T>
struct Var {
    T var;
};

// ... other operators

template<typename T>
const auto operator/(const Var<T>& lhs, const Var<T>& rhs) {
    static_assert(rhs.var != 0, "Division by 0!");

    return (lhs.var / rhs.var);
}
```

However, this is failing to compile with these generated errors...

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Data Structure Samples, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.cpp
1>c:\users\...\source\repos\data structure samples\data structure samples\datastructs.h(25): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
1>c:\users\...\source\repos\data structure samples\data structure samples\datastructs.h(25): note: failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
1>c:\users\...\source\repos\data structure samples\data structure samples\datastructs.h(25): note: see usage of 'rhs'
1>c:\users\...\source\repos\data structure samples\data structure samples\main.cpp(15): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'const auto operator /<int>(const Var<int> &,const Var<int> &)' being compiled
1>Done building project "Data Structure Samples.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

---

I can easily enough use `assert` at runtime without any problems, however, I'm struggling to figure out how to use `static_assert` properly within this context. What am I doing wrong, what am I missing here? I've searched online for various use case examples of `static_assert` but haven't found anything suitable. Even if I move the operators back inside of the class and try to use `static_assert` I still end up with very similar error messages.

Comment: How do you expects to know at **compile time** if an operand is 0?

Comment: The operands are only known at runtime (for example given from a user). It's not possible to assert them at compile time. If you don't want to throw an exception you could return a `Var` cotaining NaN or something similiar.

Comment: The class is templated, it has to deduce the type, and within the `main` function `t2` is initialized to 0. This should fail to compile... and I would think `static_assert` should be able to detect this. It's not like I'm getting the value from the console or some file at runtime.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I understand what you guys are saying about not knowing it at compile time... I could use `assert` but don't want that at runtime, if that was the case, I'd rather throw and exception.

Comment: Would there be anything within `type_traits` that could assist me with this?

Comment: I think it might be due to `Visual Studio's` wording within its error messages: "did not evaluate to a constant" and "outside of lifetime" that's throwing me off...

Comment: So in other words, It's not possible to use `static_assert` within this context...?

Comment: "constant value" usually refers to a compile time constant. I think what you want is not possible. You could use [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) so your function can _only_ be used at compile time. But that's probably not what you want.

Comment: @churill No, it's not... I could either return an invalid value or just throw an exception, but I was trying to avoid throwing exceptions for these sets of classes...

Comment: Sorry, but C++ does not work this way.

Comment: What would be the more appropriate choice, `return` a custom `NaN`, use `assert` at `runtime`, or just `throw` an `exception`?

Comment: @churill I added my own answer as a possible solution that I could work with... Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around, I found a possible solution that can work. There are no program abortions from either asserting or throwing exceptions.

However, there is a little bit of concern when using this within a later calculation... This would force me to write the rest of the source code in these terms and would have to check everything to make sure it's not a `NaN` to prevent any further computations to abort early without exiting the application.

With that being said, here is what I have done and this is what my operator now looks like...

```
#include <cmath>

template<typename T>
struct Var {
    T var;
};

template<typename T>
const auto operator/(const Var<T>& lhs, const Var<T>& rhs) {
    return (rhs.var == 0) ? nan("0") : (lhs.var / rhs.var);
}
```

And when I run the same program, `nan` is printed to the console.